# One Page Scroller Site not working in IE8 & IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, responsive-design, internet-explorer-9

This page loads fine in all browser except IE8 & IE9. http://www.yumpu.com/de/features/dropbox/?cc=true

The one page scroller is not scrolling in IE8 & IE9. Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Mahendra

Answer (score 0):

That is bug in script zenbox.js. In my internet explorer i get the error in "File: zenbox.js, Line: 39, Column: 7"

You can debug in internet explorer following this http://www.askvg.com/internet-explorer-10-allows-to-switch-between-ie5-ie7-ie8-and-ie9-rendering-modes/